# getElementsByTagName not working in Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, getelementsbytagname

For some reason, when I try to use getElementsByTagName in my Chrome Extension, I get an empty list. For example:

***background.js***

```
document.body.onload = function(){
    chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
        alert(document.getElementsByTagName("div").length);
    });
};
```

will alert me "0". In addition, if inside my `addListener` function I create a `div` and append it to the `body`, the length becomes "1". So it seems like the extension only detects objects created after the extension was clicked...any ideas?

P.S. here is my manifest file

***manifest.json***

```
{
  "name": "tester",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "background": {
      "scripts": ["background.js"],
      "persistent": false
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `background.js` script is executed inside the background page context. Here, since you only declare a background script, your background page is generated, and doesn't have any content.

You can see the generated background page by going to chrome://extensions/ and clicking on the `Inspect views: _generated_background_page.html` link next to your extension. It will look like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <script src="background.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

As you can see, there are no `<div>` element, and therefore `document.getElementsByTagName("div").length` will return 0.

If you want to get the content of the web page, you'll have to use a [content script](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html).

Answer (score 1):

Just a follow-up, here is the code I used. It works by injecting a script into the active tab whenever the extension button is clicked (more info [here](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html#pi))

***injected.js***

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: "testscript.js"});
});
```

***testscript.js***

```
document.body.style.backgroundColor="red";
```

***manifest.json***

```
{
  "name": "injecttester",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png"
  },
  "background": {
      "scripts": ["injected.js"],
      "persistent": false
  },
  "permissions": [
  "activeTab",
  ]
}
```